# Connection to remote mysql from localhost

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have searched the net to no solution for a problem I am facing.

I am working on a codeigniter project which I am running on a localhost Apache Server. For the database, I am attempting to connect from CI's database.php configuration file to connect to a remote server.

The following is my configuration

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'remotedatabase.com';
$db['default']['username'] = 'remote_2102Dev';
$db['default']['password'] = '1q2w3e4r5t';
$db['default']['database'] = 'remote_cs2102';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I have tried to connect to the remote Database via mysql workbench 5.5. So that means I  have did the configuration correctly at the server side.

Please help me. Is this CI problem or there is something wrong with my settings. Thank you.

Comment: You ought to switch the value of `dbdriver` to `mysqli`. Probably won't fix your problem, but the MySQL interface is deprecated in PHP 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check host entry @ remotedatabase.com. It should be % in host
2. If your PHP version is >= 5.3 set db_debug to false: 
   $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

Comment: Great. Thank you. the second point solve my issue. May I ask what is the exact reason behind this?

Comment: Current codeigniter version is not able to debug in latest mysql version. They will update this in next release. codeigniter has stopped it's development right now as EllisLab seeking new owner for CodeIgniter.